# Can I create a new Partition in a Teradata table each time a new data load came in

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I have approx 95 Data integration interfaces that are extracting and loading data from an SAP ECC environment. Each dataset "Lands" in Teradata in a single table and is subsequently processed into a more structured and Keyed table for downstreaam consumption. This takes care of dupes and delta changes, etc.

My problem is the initial Landing table which gets truncated each time a new load comes in. If a Landed dataset fails to process forward it will be truncated and a new dataset will replace that in Landing as the next load comes in. I did not design or develop any of this, but it causes a lot of grief as well as remedy (bug) tickets.

I want to propose a solution and wanted to know if it is possible to not truncate the initial Landing table but instead create a new Partition for each Landed dataset as a new load came in. In that fashion we would avoid missing the dataset altogether. Is this possible in Teradata?

I wanted to add that we are using Informatica to connect SAP BW to Teradata as that has some bearing on the degree of difficulty we are facing. Not a huge Fan of Informatica as it is used in this case.

Thanks in advance for everyone's help,
Pat

Comment: How is the data being loaded currently? FastLoad (or the TPT Load operator) require an empty target table. MultiLoad (or the TPT Update operator) can load a table with data in it already by appending or updating the records.

Comment: Hi Rob, This is using Update Operator. I amended my post to include that we are using Informatica here to connect SAP BW to Teradata as it probably has something to do with our problem, that seems to be our biggest headache at the moment. A partitioning scheme would be the best case solution since it is how the data is managed n SAP.

Comment: Of course you might create a table with a lot of empty partitions, e.g. RANGE_N(part# BETWEEN 1 and 10000 EACH 1). When you know the max used Part# you simply load all new rows into the `Part# + 1` partition.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not to be solved by partioning the landing table. Note that  partitions are created to enhance query performance by organizing "similar" rows into Amps.

> A partitioned primary index (PPI) permits rows to be assigned to user-defined data partitions on the AMPs, enabling enhanced performance for range queries that are predicated on primary index values. For details, see Database Design and SQL Request and Transaction Processing.
>   https://docs.teradata.com/reader/Fs1l1bqzqbnO0oVqjSVP5g/MMVfdnwiK91oXhkK53mN0Q

Teradata can bulk append data on populated tables using TTP Update Operator or Multiload.